# Does android load all resources when app starts?

Tags: android

I'm looking at the Heap Dump, and I've taken out all initializing, in my Application's onCreate, as well as my Activity's.  However, I'm still seeing a 1 mb byte[] allocation (likely a bitmap?) but I'm not requesting any. The biggest image I have in my drawable folders is 21 kb (156x156, so roughly 96kb as a Bitmap?). I just can't find where this Bitmap could be coming from.  There are no themes being utilized. I am using ActionBarSherlock.

This is what MAT is showing for this allocation:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to stop system from preloading drawables. 1MB of sPreloadedDrawables is actually a small amount. More details here: [Locating and remedying cause of large heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653457/locating-and-remedying-cause-of-large-heap-size)

Comment: Well 1mb is after I gutted everything.

Comment: Nice, how did you do that? Mine is more than 7MB, making the whole app consume about 13MB, however the system shows only 5MB RAM usage. So I assume the system preloaded drawables don't count.

Comment: lol I just stopped anything loading from onCreate. Now that things are back in there, I'm at 12mb usage.

Comment: Just like me :D And what RAM usage shows the system for your app? (not logcat)